# ASP.NET Core neat if/else depending whether object is initialised?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to update a database object using:

```
  var comment = new Comment(username, message);

        if (Ticket.Comments == null)
        {
            Ticket.Comments = new List<Comment>() { comment };
        }
        else
        {
            Ticket.Comments.Add(comment);
        }
```

Is there a neater way of doing this?

Comment: You may try the Null Coalescing Operator '??'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the null coalesce operator:

```
Ticket.Comments = Ticket.Comments ?? new List<Comment>();
Ticket.Comments.Add(comment);
```

In C# 8.0, you can now use the null-colescing assignment operator (`??=`), which is a slight improvement on the above (thanks @MichałJarzyna):

```
Ticket.Comments ??= new List<Comment>();
Ticket.Comments.Add(comment);
```

However, your best bet, if you can modify the class, is to simply specify a default on the property:

```
public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
```

Then, if it's null, it will be auto-initialized to an empty list, allowing you to call `Add` without checking.

Comment: In general I would say it is ok. However, without the context you can not predict if list should be always initialized.

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't do the second option due to the way I am getting the object, but the top one (and @Michal's answer) is an improvement :)

Comment: In C# 8.0 you could do it a little better:
```Ticket.Comments ??= new List<Comment>();
Ticket.Comments.Add(comment);
```

Comment: Nice. Yeah, I forgot about that new operator.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without more information about your context. Your approach is correct, you can only do it a little shorter:

```cs
if(Ticket.Comments == null) Ticket.Comments = new List<Comment>();

Ticket.Comments.Add(comment);
```